# HTML Emails Format is not working in Outlook

Tags: html, css, angularjs, email, outlook

My HTML email format is not functioning properly in outlook. The code is using angular and bootstrap css. I have used inline css specially for outlook but when i see the email in outlook table is stretched in full screen.

I have seen some question and used the implementation suggested in answers but still showing this problem. my code is as follow:

```
     <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" width="320" style="margin-bottom: 20px;border: 1px solid #ddd; border-collapse: collapse">
        <tr ng-repeat="x in xall | orderBy:'name':false" style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-bottom-width: 2px;">
          <th style="text-align: left; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-bottom-width: 2px; width:40%;">Site Revenue</th>
          <td style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-bottom-width: 2px; width:30%;" class="number" ng-if="!data.isPrev">Â£850</td>
          <td style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-bottom-width: 2px; width:30%;" class="number" ng-if="data.isPrev">Â£500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in xall | orderBy:'name':false" style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-bottom-width: 2px;">
          <th style="text-align: left; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-bottom-width: 2px; width:40%;">Product Revenue</th>
          <td style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-bottom-width: 2px; width:30%;" class="number" ng-if="!data.isPrev">Â£650</td>
          <td style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-bottom-width: 2px; width:30%;" class="number" ng-if="data.isPrev">Â£570</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Please put some suggestions as I am totally stuck with this issue as width attribute is not functioning with outlook.

Comment: Here is a guide which shows each CSS attribute and which email clients they work in. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Guys thanks for your time and suggestions. Can you please see my code there is nothing will be wrong but i am stuck width attribute. Width is functioning very different way. So please have a look into the and let me know what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problems. 
**Here are some hints:**

1. when you give padding attribute, it should go like this: `padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;`
2. floating (float) CSS attribute is not working in outlook.
3. when you give background color which need to be given as ( bgcolor ) in table attribute.
4. Write all CSS attributes inline

Comment: You can see my code I have used inline css as well.

Comment: ( border-collapse: collapse; ) semicolon is missing, we need to consider these things when creating E-mail template.

Comment: I have a same issue in my template also.
But the padding is still not working when i give padding:5px 5px 5px 5px; like this.

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that Outlook uses Word for rendering your HTML. Word is used as an email editor. Read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following series of articles:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Hope you will find that information helpful...

Comment: Hi Eugene, I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003595/email-design-looking-different-in-outlook-in-comparison-to-other-email-clients/51003795?noredirect=1#comment89001186_51003795). I am wondering if you can help me out.